# Python function returns NaN but arithmetic operation does not

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan

I have this problem where I have a function defined that in some cases returns NaN, but most of the time it doesn't, and when it does return NaN, when I write down the equation I use in the terminal manually, it doesn't return NaN!

I don't know what could be going wrong :/

Here is my code

```
def prob(z0, N):
    Psingle = (1 - 2 * z0 / (N - 3)) ** ((N - 5) / 2)
    return Psingle
```

where z0 and N are numbers, z0 is a float and N an integer.

To give a concise example, when the input is z0 = 18.371832377470973, and N = 38 prob(z0, N) returns NaN, but the equation in the console returns a number in the order of 10^-21

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: I'm using python 2.7.13 64 bit! In particular I'm using anaconda.
Also I am using

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Both inputting the equation manually in the Python REPL and invoking the function with the same parameters gives me the same number.  https://gist.github.com/rayryeng/9bf5b502c839532f498723883b458a20.  Using Python 3.5.3 - 64 bit.

Comment: Which version of python? Are you using the same one in both cases? Do you have both a 32-bit installation and a 64-bit installation and you're switching between them by accident?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.13 64 bit. I'm adding that to the original question!

Comment: In Python 2, `((N - 5) / 2)` does integer division, so when `N` is 38, the value of that expression is the integer 16.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Does the code where the result is NaN run in Python 3, or does it have an import of the form `from __future__ import division`?  Because if `((N - 5) / 2)` does floating point division, the result is 16.5, and then you are trying to raise a negative value to a fractional power.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that I am using from _future_ import division!

Comment: In a new ipython session, if I *first* do `from __future__ import division`, and then define `prob`, `z0`, and `N` as you have done, I get the error `ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power` when I run `prob(z0, N)`.

Comment: Also, if I define `z0` to be a `numpy.float64` instead of a python float (e.g. `z0 = np.float64(18.371832377470973)`), I get a warning, and `nan` is returned. Please edit the question to include the *complete* context in which the problem is occurring.